# How to open a saved Google Onhub diagnostic report?

Tags: report, diagnostics

I have a saved Google Onhub diagnostic report. With Notepad I can't see the whole file, because it's encrypted. A Hex-Editor won't open it neither.
Can someone tell me if there is a program to open it correctly?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's a [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) encoded file, containing an archive of files and other data entries.

There's a [Go project on github](https://github.com/benmanns/onhub) that decodes it, and even if you don't run their Go code, you can use the protobuf schema that's available in that repository to decode the report in whichever environment you choose using the protobuf bindings available in the [official website](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/)